# freeing a linked list

Tags: c, malloc

I have defined a linked list as follows

```
typedef struct uniquePattern{
  int pattern[*m]; 
  int position; 
  struct uniquePattern *previous;
  double backValues[]; 
}uniquePattern;
```

I add several elements to the list such that the first element has always previous = NULL. Then I try to free the memory using the next function.

```
  void free_ll(uniquePattern *head){
   uniquePattern *tmp;
    while (head != NULL){
     tmp = head;
     head = head->previous;
     free(tmp);
};
```

};

I get no errors. However in the examples of the textbook appears that the author free the contents of the linked list before freeing the linked list itself. For example:

```
typedef struct names{
  char *name;
  struct names *previous;
};
```

If name points to a string literal then may make sense to remove the string literal before removing the struct.

Is my code right? is my reasoning right?

EDIT:

`double backValues[];`  contains an array that increases lenght by one each time an element is added to the list. For example, if the user was adding coordinates of towns that he has visited and I need to calculate the euclidean distance then when the user adds a 4th town, backValues will be lenght 3, containing the distance between 4-1 4-2 and 4-3.

So I have a counter that knows how many elements are in the list, say, `counter` and each
 time I allocate a bit more memory when creating a new element. `(counter-1)*sizeof(double)`, for that array.

I malloc the array at the same time I malloc the struct (I do not call malloc twice).

Comment: If you have pointers inside the structure that you allocate (or files, or other resources you create or open) then those *might* need to be destroyed/released/closed/free. I say *might* because if those resource is in use somewhere else you can't do it.

Comment: "int pattern[*m];" ? "struct *names = previous;" ?

Comment: *m is an integer defined as user parameter, the error is corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in freeing the node.  Many nodes will hold their *data* as pointers to other areas that have been `malloc`'ed themselves.  Judging from your comment, I think you know that.  Looking at your structure, I'm a bit worried about `double backValues[]`.

However you specifically mention a string literal.  No, you cannot `free` a string literal, or perhaps I should say that if you try then the effect is undefined.  A string literal is normally held in read-only memory somewhere, not on the heap.  You should only `free` something that has been created using `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.

But that might be semantics, if by "string literal" you mean an array of chars that has been created on the heap (`malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`) then yes, it should be freed *before* the node.  If you do not then you will loose track of the pointer, and you have a memory leak.

How is the memory allocated for `backValues`?  I think we should be told.

Comment: I see, the thing is that I find some functions that are sneaky when using malloc. For example, strdup uses malloc in secret so that is why the book was freeing the content before freeing the struct. I have added how I allocate the memory of back Values.

Comment: Not sure that `strdup` does things "in secret", the standard says: *The returned pointer can be passed to free()*.  The book should have mentioned that though, so I agree it was less than clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pointers inside the structure that hold reference to some allocated memory chunk, you need to free them before you free the nodes of the list.
For instance, assume a simple node definition:

```
typedef struct node_struct{
 int *arr;
 struct node_struct *next;
}node_t;
```

And you create a node:

```
node_t tmp_node;
node_t *node_ptr;
node_ptr = &tmp_node;
```

And you dynamically allocate space for the integer array "arr" as:

```
node_ptr->arr = malloc(ARR_SIZE * sizeof(int));
```

In this case, make sure you free the dynamically allocated array "arr" of the node before de-allocating the node itself.